# Upgrading to 14.04 didn't update my kernel

Tags: kernel, update-manager, 14.04

I've updated my Ubuntu version from 13.10 to 14.04 last week using the `update-manager`. 
However, my kernel version did not update:

```
$ uname -r
3.11.0-12-generic
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
Description:     Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:         14.04
Codename:        trusty
```

This makes virtualbox and any other thing that needs updated linux-headers to not work (The old 3.11 linux-headers are not present in the repo).

I know [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade) but I want to use the default kernel that came with trusty (I think it's 3.13.0-24), so that I know everything is supported.

How can I update my kernel to the correct version?

Comment: i installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm still trying to find a way to upgrade the kernel.